# Как передать значения из props в state?

Tags: reactjs

часть кода:

```
       constructor(){
        super(...arguments);
        this.state = {
             cards: this.props.cards,
             showAddCard: false
        };
       }

    render(){
        console.log(this.state.cards);
        console.log(this.props.cards);
...
}
```

`this.props.cards` является массивом

`console.log(this.state.cards);` - выводит пустой массив (в этом и проблема!!!)
`console.log(this.props.cards);` - выводит привильный массив.
Как правильно засунуть содержимое `props` в `state`?

Comment: вы уверены что внутри конструктора this.props.cards не пустой?

Comment: @ИльяПаймушкин, Уверен, для проверки поставил после `super()` `console.log(this.props.cards);` - выводит привильный массив, т.е. не пустой.

Comment: засунуть то можно, вопрос в другом - а нужно ли засовывать?

Answer (score 0):

У вас весьма странный конструктор. Попробуйте заменить его на такой:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
         cards: this.props.cards,
         showAddCard: false
    };
   }
```

Comment: И у вас в конструкторе есть странность. Опечатка, должно быть так: `cards: props.cards,`